# capturing shell exit code in perl

Tags: perl

I am executing  shell command using perl using open 3

```
   local ( *HANDLE_IN, *HANDLE_OUT, *HANDLE_ERR );

    my $pid = open3( *HANDLE_IN, *HANDLE_OUT, *HANDLE_ERR, @cmd_args );
```

where @cmd_args = my shell command

My shell returns below exit codes

```
0: command executed successfully

>0: error in executing the command
```

How can i capture the exit code from shell in my perl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy, just look at [the good old perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html):

```
$pid = open3(\*CHLD_IN, \*CHLD_OUT, \*CHLD_ERR,
    'some cmd and args', 'optarg', ...);

my($wtr, $rdr, $err);
use Symbol 'gensym'; $err = gensym;
$pid = open3($wtr, $rdr, $err,
    'some cmd and args', 'optarg', ...);

waitpid( $pid, 0 );
my $child_exit_status = $? >> 8;
```

`$child_exit_status` then contains the status of the program executed.

Another method to use is `${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE}` which I'm using especially when executing external commands via backticks:

```
my $fancyresult = `ls -lsahR /`;

if (${^CHILD_ERROR_NATIVE} != 0) {
    ...
```

Comment: You can just as easily use `$?` for backticks too.

Comment: @constantlearner The command you are calling is probably not finished.

Answer (score 2):

You need to eventually reap the child using `wait` or `waitpid`. When you do, [`$?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24?) will be set as follows.

```
waitpid($pid, 0);
die "Can't waitpid: $!" if $? < 0;
die "Child killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F ) if $? & 0x7F;
die "Child returned error ".( $? >> 8 ) if $? >> 8;
print "Child ran successfully!\n";  # if $? == 0
```

Comment: After adding these lines my script hangs